# php htmlentities corrupt string

Tags: php, html-entities, mysql-real-escape-string

For security reasons I wanted to add a function to turn strings to safe format by using the code below. in normal English characters it works fine, but when i use Amharic characters like `ከበደ` I am getting different string like `áŠ¨á‰ á‹°`, what shall I do.

```
    echo safestring("ከበደ");
    //the string after echo is absolutely changed


    function safestring($str){

        //make the string from SQL injection
        $str  = htmlentities($str);
        $str= mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        return $str;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, first you have provide the `charset` for your document

**HTML**

just add the following code the `<head>` element of your HTML

```
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

**PHP**

for json  you can use the `header` function of `php` like so

```
         header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

In order to prevent from losing any chars from the string you can use the code below

```
        function safestring($string){
            $string = trim($string);
            $string = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $string);
            $string = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $string);
            $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
            return  $string;
        }
```